# invalid channel id error in gcm chrome when trying to send message

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-gcm

I'm developing a chrome extension to receive messages from Gcm push services.
I developed the extension to get the channel id and I have the php code to send the message to gcm server. The php code is returning error from gcm server like this.

> ERROR:{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "invalidParameter", "message": "Invalid channel ID: {0}", "locationType": "parameter", "location": "channelId" } ], "code": 400, "message": "Invalid channel ID: {0}" } }

I have published the chrome extension to chrome web store to public. Here is the link.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/first-test/eooaplfpgeapcnniknheiodecggeipko

My php code to send message to gcm server..

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="pushform" method="POST" action="sendMessage.php">
Chrome Channel ID :<input type="text" name="channel" size="170" value="" />            
Message : <input type="text" name="message" size="100" maxlength="100" value
=" "/>
<input type="submit" value="Send Message" />
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['channel']))
{
$channel = $_POST['channel'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$url= 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';

//If you would have got refresh token
$refresh_token = "MY_REFRESH_TOKEN_FROM_GOOGLE"; //set ehre

$data = array();
$data['client_id']="MY_CLIENT_ID"; //set there
$data['client_secret']="MY_SECRET_CODE"; //set here
$data['refresh_token']=$refresh_token;
$data['grant_type']="refresh_token";



 // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => http_build_query($data),
),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$obj = json_decode($result);

if(!isset($obj->access_token))
{
die("ERROR: unable to get access token.\n".$result);
}

$access_token = $obj->access_token;


$url ="https://www.googleapis.com/gcm_for_chrome/v1/messages";
$data = json_encode(array(
    'channelId' => $channel,
    'subchannelId' => "1",
    'payload'=> $message
));

$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => 
     "https://www.googleapis.com/gcm_for_chrome/v1/messages",
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $data,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    )
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(strstr($result,"error"))
{
    echo "ERROR:".$result;
}
else
    echo "Successfully sent message to Chrome";

}
?>
```

My background.js file in my chrome extension is.

```
var GCM_SENDERID = 'MY_SENDER_ID';
var GCM_SENDER = GCM_SENDERID + '@gcm.googleapis.com';

    // We don't expect errors, but let's be good citizens 
    and register error handlers

     var errorLogger = function() {
    console.error.apply(console, arguments);
     };
     chrome.gcm.onSendError.addListener(errorLogger);

     chrome.gcm.onMessagesDeleted.addListener(errorLogger);


    // This event handles incoming messages

     chrome.gcm.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    // Who says comments don't get read?
     console.info('got GCM message', msg);

    // Incoming GCM data: we'll add callback here later [1].

   });


   // First things first, register with the GCM server at application start.

  chrome.gcm.register([GCM_SENDERID], function(regid) {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError || regid === -1) {
  console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);

  return;
 }

 console.info('registration id :, reg',regid);

  //chrome.app.window.create("pushhome.html?regid="+regid);
  window.open("pushhome.html?regid="+regid);
  // Connected OK: we'll add callback here later [2].

   });
```

My manifest.json file

```
       {
     "app": {
      "background": {
     "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
       }
       },
      "description": "geting registration-id. ",


       "name": "First-test",
       "permissions": [  "gcm","notifications" ],
        "version": "2.0"
         }
```

Comment: More logging on the server side is needed. Catch / log the exact CURL request before it goes out..

Comment: hi!! thank for the reply....but i didnt get you..

Comment: Your problem is that you send an invalid request to the server. The error may be helpful, but you really need to capture the whole request as your server sends it to debug this.

Comment: but it says the channel id i got from the server is invalid...what else the server can say...